# PHP How to loop through a nested array with a variable filled from initial array looping?

Tags: php, html, arrays, loops, foreach

Alright, I have an array `$parentArray` through which I am looping to render certain fields. Within this loop I have a `variable` called `$specialCases`, which is supposed to save other defined fields such as `foo` and `bar`. Later on within the initial looping of `$parrentArray`, I would like to loop through the array `$specialCases` to render `foo` and `bar`.

How can I do that?

Below is my trial but it is not working. I only get `1` value in the array `$specialCases` instead of an expected `2`.

```js
        <?php foreach( $this->parrentArray as $strName => $arrField ): ?>
          <?php if ( $this->{$strName} !== null && $this->{$strName} !== '' ): ?>       
            <?php if ( is_array( $this->{$strName} ) ): ?>
              <?php $this->{$strName} = implode( ', ', array_map( function( $varValue ) {
                if ( is_string ( $varValue ) ) return $varValue;
                if ( is_array ( $varValue ) ) return $varValue['title'];
                return $varValue;
                }, $this->{$strName} )) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>         
            <?php if ( is_string( $this->{$strName} ) ): ?>
              <?php if(!in_array($strName, $ignore)): ?>
                <?php if( $strName == 'foo' || $strName == 'bar'): ?>
                  <?php $specialCases[] = $strName ?>
                  <?php var_dump($specialCases) ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if( $strName !== 'foo'): ?>
                  <?php if( $strName !== 'bar'): ?>
                    <div class="ctlg_entity <?= $strName ?>">
                      <?php if( $strName !== 'description'): ?>
                        <span class="ctlg_entity_name"> <?= $arrField['title']; ?>:</span>
                      <?php endif; ?>
                        <div class="ctlg_entity_value">
                          <?php if ($strName == "foo" || $strName == "bar"):  ?>
                            <?php echo count($specialCases); ?>
                            <?php foreach ($specialCases as $key => $value): ?>
                              <!-- My issue is here, for some reasin $specialCases only has 1 value instead of an expected 2 -->
                              <span class="filter_value special">Filter value comes here,</span>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                          <?php endif; ?>
                            <span class="detail_value"><?= $this->{$strName}; ?></span>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                  <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
              <?php endif; ?>                  
            <?php endif; ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, expected result, and current result

Comment: Also, this code is almost impossible to read. Why are you opening and closing `<?php` tags on every single line?

Comment: `$ignore` is undefined... oh, and your code is illegible :-)

Comment: That because you doing the loop nested. During the initial loop you adding the first element (foo or bar) and then get to the second loop - in that case it is obvious you will only get the first one

Comment: @dWinder yes thank you! I see what you mean! It obviously cannot have two fields because it is not even getting to the point where its adding the second field. Thank you! Apologies about the ugly code, not well versed in PHP, I'm editing already existing code.